# 'All' filter on report causing error "[BC30516] Overload resolution failed"

Tags: filter, expression, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to add a filter to a report.  I thought this would give me all records when “All” is selected since the filter wouldn’t take effect and if it didn’t = “All” then it would kick off the filter.

```
‌=iif(Parameters!vType.Value <> "All", iif(Parameters!vType.Value = "Red", "Red", iif(Parameters!vType.Value = "Green", "Green", "Yellow")))
```

I thought this would work but I’m getting this message:

```
The FilterValue expression for the dataset "Dashboard_Test' contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Iif' accepts this number of arguments.
```

I’ve checked commas, brackets, etc., and don’t see anything wrong.  Can anyone tell me what this message means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first iif requires a condition if true, try this as an example:

=iif(Parameters!vType.Value(0) <> "All", "Green", iif(Parameters!vType.Value(0) = "Red", "Red", iif(Parameters!vType.Value(0) = "Green","Green","Yellow")))

I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve but hopefully this helps.

Comment: That helped a lot.  Thanks for the suggestion